# why having this error when trying added firebase to flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am Facing error while trying to add Firebase on Flutter project, I have followed the instructions step by step and when I  run the app error appear,I tried to remove cloud_firestore dependencies but same error appear again with firebase_auth.
PS:The google-services.json was added to 'project/android/app'  .

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
     Searched Location:
     C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\src\nullnull\google-services.json
 C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\src\debug\google-services.json
 C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
 C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.1\android\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 14s
 Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
   Exited (sigterm)
```

PubSpec.yaml file :

```
 dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   firebase_core: ^1.0.1
   cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
   firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
```

build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }

   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
}

  allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
  }

   rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
 subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
  }
   subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
 buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
   }

    allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
   }

     rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
      subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
     }
      subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
     }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Comment: `File google-services.json is missing`. Have you added `.json` ?

Comment: yes I added it .

Comment: what is your ```google-services.json``` location?

Comment: "./android/app/google-services.json"